# How to parse namespace XML in Chrome 24 and jQuery 1.8.2?

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, google-chrome

I am trying to parse the following XML:

```
<catalog>
   <ns:book>
       <author>Author</author>
   </ns:book>
</catalog>
```

I have researched extensively and found the following (past) solutions and none of them currently work in Chrome 24 with jQuery 1.8

```
  $(xml).find("ns\\:book").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).find("author").text() + "<br />");
  });
```

nor

```
  $(xml).find("book").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).find("author").text() + "<br />");
  });
```

nor

```
  $(xml).find("[nodeName=ns:book]").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).find("author").text() + "<br />");
  });
```

In my research, it would seem that this is primarily a chrome issue and not a jQuery issue.  Is there an accepted solution?  Is there a better js library to use for XML parsing?

Comment: first method works in Chrome 22... try this in your version  http://jsfiddle.net/zeGWs/

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same issue today.
With jQuery 1.8.3 and Chrome 23 I've noticed 2 cases:

```
//Data is a string representing XML
var data = "<catalog><ns:book><author>Author</author></ns:book></catalog>";
```

Case 1

```
//Case 1
var xml = $.parseXML(data); 
//xml is a XmlDocument
$(xml).find("book");
//$(xml) is a Document
//works directly, can't seem to be able to use namespace.
```

Case 2.

```
var xml = $(data);
//xml is an Object
$(xml).find('ns\\:book')
//works just fine
```